# PHP secure email is blocking the false emails but letting the registration go through

Tags: php, forms, security, email, spam

I am trying to make a form that is secure from spam and sends a simple email to the person who registers.

Im quite new to PHP and the problem im faced with is when the form is submitted with a false email address in the email field, it brings up the error message stating that the email is invalid, but still lets the registration go through adding it to the database.

here is the code

```
function spamcheck($field) {
    // filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
    // address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
    $field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    // filter_var() validates the e-mail
    // address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
    if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {
    // if "email" is filled out, proceed
    // check if the email address is invalid
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
    if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
        die("<font color='red'>Your email address is invalid, please try again.</font><br/><br/><form><INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'></form>");
    }
    else {//send email
        $to = "$email";
        $from = "name@mywebsite.com";
        $message = "Just a message";
        $subject = "Subject";

        mail($to, $message, $subject, "From: $from", "-f$from");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code to add it to the db is not shown, however it wont be sending the mail - in which case, make sure the call to save the registration to the db is in your section where you send the mail.

Comment: Hi, thanks, the email is getting through and the code is just below it to add it to the database, i moved it about (just below the values) and same problem.

Comment: It cant be showing you the "your email address is invalid" message and send the mail - that doesnt follow the posted code - if the code for the db insertion was not in same {} as the mail command, then it would do it irrelevant of the spam status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem here is, that your check-function first sanitizes the email address, and afterwards validates the sanitized email. That means, the check-function checks the sanitized email, but outside of the function you are still working with the invalid email.

So either do the sanitizing outside of the check function, or in my opinion even better, only validate the input without sanitization (better to make the user aware that he typed it incorrect, than trying to repair it).

```
function checkEmail($input)
{
  return filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Edit:

Actually there must be another problem, because when the code `die(...Your email address is invalid...)` is executed, the processing of the page stops. We would need to see the part of the code, which writes to the database.

Comment: $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (title, username, password, email, firstname, secondname, age, 
nationality, town_city, language_to_study, how_to_study, language_level,
monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday, telephone,  

) VALUES (

'$title', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$firstname', '$secondname', '$age', 
'$nationality', '$town_city', '$language_to_study', '$how_to_study', '$language_level',
'$monday', '$tuesday', '$wednesday', '$thursday', '$friday', '$saturday', '$sunday', '$telephone',)");

function spamcheck($field)

Comment: @Paul Meadows - So you are inserting the new user, before you test the email address? The query should only be executed, **after** the validation of the email was successful. The query should be at the same place, where you call the `mail()` function.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, ive placed it all above inserting it into the database and it seems to have worked, thank you for your help, ive been racking my brains about this for hours ha.

Comment: @Paul Meadows - You are welcome! Maybe i misunderstood your comment, but if you do the insert query after the `if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])) {...}`, somebody could leave the email empty, the code would **not** check the email address, but it would be inserted into the database anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, Print Mailcheck see what its saying.

die('Mail Check: ' . $mailcheck);

If its nothing set it equal to ===

if($mailcheck === false){

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry im a complete novice, should i put this code infront of if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
        die(